# Editable Content Control in Word

Tags: 2010, word

I have a workflow in SP2010 that updates a Word template using content controls. This all works fine until someone wants to edit the text within the content control. Whilst they can add to it and delete it they cannot edit the actual text that has been passed in from Sharepoint.

What can I do to make this content editable? It seems weird that it can be delete and added to but not edited - my inital thought is that is was a permissions problem but if that was the case, adding and deleting would also be blocked.

Am I missing something?